# Javascript RegExp or regular expression control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have 20-25 textboxes in the form. should I use regular expression control in my aspx page or i should use Java-script RegExp. I want to know this in following context.

1. Preformance
2. Memory Management

**EDIT**
The above choice is required for validation purposes.

Comment: What are you doing with those 20-25 textboxes?  What to you need regex for?

Comment: Don't forget rule number 1: You CAN'T trust the client. You probably will have to validate server-side, because you can't be sure that client-side validation hasn't been skipped. Client side validations are good to add some instant feedback to the user, but you can't depend on it.

Comment: basically, as you can't trust user input you should do it on the server anyways. for better user experience you can also do it on the client (additionally)

Comment: @julio.olvr- Server side validation means I will add validation controls or i will do the validation in .cs file?

Comment: @StackOverflowUser: Server side validation in code behind ie., .cs file..

Comment: Should i validate the data on both side i.e. Server side and client side. Please confirm.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser: yes, ofcourse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[regular expression validator control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e(v=vs.100).aspx) will do the validation both at client and server side.

As far I know there is no Performance and Memory management issues regarding client side validation..

Comment: As regular expression support java script. So, what if java script is blocked ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

asp will need resources on your server
js will need resources on the client

So if you're using asp you will need a much more powerful server, if you're using js and filtering long texts it might render slowly on slow clients.